# What is the lifetime of assignments to fields marked as transient within a spring/jpa application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm not sure this is the right question or set of frameworks.

The list of frameworks I'm aware of being involved to some degree here are:

- Spring
- Hibernate
- QueryDSL

I've been trying to get to grips with a web application using this stuff on the server side and had basically come to the conclusion that the server was a collection of static methods, which had state eg objects etc for only the duration of individual method calls, with basically a huge pile of reflective code generation thrown in to make things <strike>confusing</strike> easy.

I've just come across the transient annotation and this has thrown my idea of what is going on out the window.

Im not really sure what's relevant so I'll describe the situation I'm looking at:

At login time we are querying a table in the database which has user information in it.

**Update**

This is from a class that implements UserDetailsService (a spring class) in the method that defines (loadUserByUsername(String username).

This gets called in a class extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider which is set as the authentication provider.  In practice this means it gets called as users login to our webapp.  There can be more than one user logged in at any given time.

---

This is done using a jpa repository and some querydsl predicate.

```
UserDetails userDetails = userRepository.findOneLoaded(UserPredicates.hasUserNameEqualsIgnoreCase(username));
```

Then comes the bit that is confusing:

```
    Division division = divisionRepository.findDefaultDivision((User) userDetails);
    ((User) userDetails).setCurrentDivision(division);
```

And that's it.  The setter just sets a field which is marked as @Transient and then none of the code in this stack uses this value.

It does have usages scattered throughout the project however, which would presumably fail (there aren't any tests so that could actually be the case!) if it was null.

What is happening here?  How long do these assignments last?  And I suppose on a related note, how long are the other 'objects' lasting for?  Is my mental model of this stuff as just being static method calls to read and write to the database wrong?  It might explain why the application guzzles so much memory!  I'm assuming a cached version of each row of the database isn't hanging around - is it something more like an in memory dictionary of key value pairs for each row that gets assigned to it when they get loaded from the database?

We're trying to refactor away from some of nastier parts of this stuff and this has made me a bit worried that there's more magic I don't know about yet!

Comment: where are those bits coming from exactly? Is this your code?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I've updated my question.  I'm not sure I'd say it's my code but its code in the project I'm working on!

Comment: Reading this question, it seems to me that you need to read the documentation of the frameworks you're using.

Comment: @JBNizet unfortunately that could be the answer for any problem to do with pretty much any framework.  The problem in java seems to be that the frameworks are too large and likewise that the documenation is very verbose without actually containing useful information

Comment: They also seem to lack the basic information "this is a framework for doing 'blah'.  The reason to do this is 'blah'"